# How do I install Qt 6 in Debian Bookworm?

Tags: debian, apt, qt

A few years ago, I remember installing Qt 5 with a single `apt install ...` command, although I don't remember exactly which package I was installing.

Looking to install Qt on a new Debian 12 Bookworm machine, I found that it's not that straightforward any longer:

- The official site seems to [suggest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/get-and-install-qt.html) some online installer which requires to create an account on Qt's website. Moreover, it looks like there is only a [10-day evaluation](https://www.qt.io/download) of a paid version of the framework that is available for the download, not the open source version.
- The tutorials ([example](https://vitux.com/compiling-your-first-qt-program-in-debian-10/)) mention `apt install qt5-default`, however, it seems that there is no `qt6-default` or `qt5-default` in Bookworm's APT sources.
- Bookworm's sources [do have packages related to Qt 6](https://packages.debian.org/source/bookworm/qt6-base), however, it doesn't seem right to have to install about twenty five packages by hand.

What's the correct way to install Qt 6 on Debian 12 Bookworm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `qt6-base-dev` will pull in all the base packages needed for Qt 6 development (including all the packages you found). Depending on what you’re trying to do, you may need to install other development packages; for example, `qt6-tools-dev` if you need the Qt 6 Tools, `qt6-charts-dev` if you need Qt 6 Charts, etc.